# If start with a specific string, how to routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, wildcard

There are many url paths, but they start with a specific string.

Is there a way to route using wildcards in this case?

Or is there a better way to be an alternative?

ex) sell-computer, sell-phone, ..., buy-computer, buy-phone, ...

```
path: 'market',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: MarketComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'sell-**',
        component: SellComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'buy-**',
        component: BuyComponent
      }
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pass the sell/buy type as param :

```
  {
    path: 'sell/:type',
    component: SellComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'buy/:type',
    component: BuyComponent
  }
```

or if you want to keep the structure :

```
  {
    path: 'sell-:type',
    component: SellComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'buy-:type',
    component: BuyComponent
  }
```

And then in you component get the param from the current route.

Comment: The good thing about this way of doing it, is that the :type has an included parameter, which can be used for fetching data.

Comment: path: 'sell-:type' --> This method does not seem to work. Is it right?